# VBA Macro: Delete a row based on an error value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an Excel file.

**Note**: I am using the italian language version of Excel.
I must delete all the rows that store the value `#VALUE!`. That value must be always searched inside the same column. The first row must be excluded from this process.

then I loop all the rows in the following way:

```
For i = 2 To Lastrow
    If (IsError(Sheets("Report").Cells(i, 5).Value)) Then
        Sheets("Report").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Surprisingly enough, this code doesn't delete all the rows that store an error value. I've tried to use other conditions, based on the values present in other cells, but I get always the same result. I don't know what to think of it anymore.

Comment: Another (and more faster) way is to filter cells with errors and delete them in one step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
For i = 2 To Lastrow
```

with:

```
For i = Lastrow to 2 Step -1
```

We run the look **backwards** to avoid corrupting the loop counter.

Comment: Dear Gary's Student, it works. I'm really really grateful!